# Safari on iPhone set default image name as image.jpg on input type file input

Tags: php, ios, iphone, codeigniter, safari

I've using CI 2.2 to made simple form with attachment/file upload. Everything working fine except on iphone safari browser. When people attach an image from iphone safari, the filename was turn into image.jpg. This causing problem where attachment from different person keep showing same image.

I used filename encryption provided by CI but still no luck.

Here is the model:

- function for take value from field:

  ```
     function check_field()
     {
       $ship_date = $this->input->post('date');
       $image_data = $this->upload->data();
       $field_data = [
         'ship_date'       => $ship_date,
          'ship_boxes'      => $this->input->post('boxes'),
          'ship_attach'     => $image_data['file_name'],
          'image_path'      => $image_data['file_path'],
          'ship_req_fund'   => $this->input->post('option'),
          'ship_amount_req' => $this->input->post('amount'),
          'ship_emp_id'     => $this->session->userdata('id')
       ];

       $this->db->insert('shipment', $field_data);
    }
  ```

  - attachment function

    ```
    function attachment()
    {
      $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
      $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|zip|rar|pdf';
      $config['max_size'] = '3000';
      $config['max_width'] = '2000';
      $config['max_height'] = '2000';
      $config['encrypt_name'] = true;
      $this->upload->initialize($config);
    }
    ```
  - sending message to email:

    ```
    function send_message()
    {
    $config = [
        'protocol'  => 'mail',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => '*******@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => '*******',
        'mailtype'  => 'html',
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1',
        'wordwrap'  => TRUE
    ];

    $image_data = $this->upload->data();
    $image_link = $image_data['client_name'];

    $message = '<h3>Below is the shipment data you have submitted.</h3>';
    $message .= '<p><b>Shipment date</b>: ' . $this->input->post('date') . '</p>';
    $message .= '<p><b>Number of boxes</b>: ' . $this->input->post('boxes') . '</p>';
    if($this->upload->data())
    {
       $message .= '<p></b>Attachment</b>: <a href="' . base_url() . 'uploads/' . $image_link . '">Click Here</a></p>';
    }
    else
    {
        $message .= '<p></b>Attachment</b>: No attachment</p>';
    }
    if($this->input->post('option') == 1)
    {
        $message .= '<p><b>Request fund</b>: Yes</p>';
        $message .= '<p><b>Amount of funds requested</b>: $' . $this->input->post('amount') . '</p>';
    }
    else
    {
        $message .= '<p><b>Request fund</b>: No</p>';
    }

    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('*****@gmail.com', '*****');
    $this->email->to($this->session->userdata('email'));
    $this->email->subject('Shipment detail');
    $this->email->message($message);
    $this->email->send();
    }
    }
    ```

Any one meet same problem in the past or i have set it within wrong way? if this really caused by browser, any method to resolving the file upload in iphone safari?

Thanks,

Comment: 1. A comment like the above will discourage help. 2. The question is incomplete, what is "CI", a full name would help. 3. SO discourages down voters from giving a reason because many times the person downvoted revenge down votes that person. I recently down voted a bad answer and had 5 of my old questions down voted. 4. I have doubts that the names are "encrypted", rather some other scheme to create unique names. Encryption has a very specific meaning. 5. I did not down vote the question.

Comment: I noticed this issue is fixed in iOS10 Safari, which is good.

Comment: @AndyGaskell That really2 great news.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a UUID for the name. Relying on a client provided name being unique is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function for the same problem you have -

```
    <?php 
    get_filename($filename)
{
$fparts= explode(".",$filename);
$extension = $fparts[count($fparts)-1]; 
unset($fparts[count($fparts)-1]);
$filenamewoextension=implode(".", $fparts);

counter=0;

while(file_exists($filename))
{

$filename = $filenamewoextension . $counter . $extension;

}
return $filename;
}
```

Comment: The problem is from the iphone safari, the filename for image type always be renaming to image.jpg or image.png no matter what the original file name. I think implode would not work too.

Comment: My answer would rename that to image1.png or image1.jpg or if that exists image2.png or image2.jpg that would prevent overwriting of files on your server

Comment: The problem is not overwriting since the name encryption was enabled. So every attachment was renamed to 32 random string. The problem is its fail on iphone safari.

Comment: @YashSodha After 10,000 images or so things *might* start getting slow.